# Divide from base 10 to base 60?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, time

I am making an overtime calculator but I get the results in base 10 that can confuse the end user.

for example for 30 minutes of OT the answer is 0.50 that can be confused with 50 minutes, or 45 minutes with 0.75.

how can I divide the result, for example 2700.0, in a way that give a base 60 result, 45 in this case??

EXTRA: how can I make 6300 == 1:45 ??

for more info this is the model: https://github.com/pauloat/CalculadoraSICA/blob/desarrollo/app/models/calculadora.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.at(6300).utc.strftime("%H:%M")
=> "01:45"
```

(Assuming you need it for displaying, so a string is fine.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a combination of [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) and [hours](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-hours).

```
distance_of_time_in_words(0, 0.5.hours)
```

results in 30 minutes.